Boot Screen Errors
I recently shifted to Ubunutu 24.04 LTS in my Acer Aspire 7 laptop. I installed Veracrypt the day before the incident to create password-protected folders. I had to mount a folder to upload the files in. After that, I will not be able to boot into Ubuntu. So I checked bootlog and these are the errors that are listed in it:


ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PC00.RP08.CMDR], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230628/psargs-330)
ACPI Error: Aborting method _SB.PC00.RP05.PCRP._ON due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230628/psparse-529)
pnp 00:04: disabling [mem 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff] because it overlaps 0000:00:02.0 BAR 9 [mem 0x00000000-0xdfffffff 64bit pref]
hpet_acpi_add: no address or irqs in _CRS
unchecked MSR access error: tried to write 0x000000000000ffff at rIP: 0xffffffff96ec4b04 (native_write_msr+x4/8x40)
pci 10000:e0:10.0: Primary bus is hard wired to e
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
profiles/sap/server.c:sap_server_register() sap driver initialization failed.
sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
systemd[1]: Failed to start plymouth-quit.service Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen.
Gdm: GdmSession: no session desktop files installed, aborting...
Failed to start gdm.service GNOME Display Manager


I am relatively new to these and don't know exactly what to do. I tried doing things mentioned in some forums, but none seem to fix this. So please help me fix these errors. Thanks in advance.
PS: I installed Nvidia drivers a week prior. I checked whether those are the reasons for the error by finding the right driver provided by Nvidia, and the driver I have is the same as the most recent one. If there is any possibility of error among these, please tell me that too.
PSPS: I tried adding dash to dock to my Ubuntu through gnome-extensions. After installing it, I got these errors before booting into Ubuntu. But in previous cases, it booted into Ubuntu. But today, it didn't. Also, I am dual-booting Ubuntu alongside Windows.
